# Convert columns to rows grouped by day

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I've been struggling with this for a while, using groups, pivot tables etc.
My data looks like this:

```
Date            Time        Reading
01/01/2015  1:18:20         13.4
01/01/2015  6:04:59          8.7
01/01/2015  21:16:57        21.1
01/02/2015  0:12:53         20.2
01/02/2015  6:52:06         16.1
01/02/2015  11:03:25        20.8
01/02/2015  15:47:29        15.3
01/02/2015  16:36:51        12.0
01/02/2015  20:11:22         9.1
01/03/2015  0:06:23         13.4
01/03/2015  6:31:24         19.3
```

and I would like it to look like this:

```
Date            Time         Reading     Time       Reading       Time     etc.
01/01/2015      1:18:20      13.4        6:04:59     8.7          21:16:57
01/02/2015      0:12:53      20.2        6:52:06    16.1         11:03:25
01/03/2015      0:06:23      13.4        6:31:24    19.3
etc.
```

Please can you help me.....this is for my doctor?

Comment: Not sure from the formatting, but try searching "excel transpose"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to get you started, perhaps try the following:

1) Assuming the data is in columns A, B & C to start with, insert a column in front of A, and add the following formula in A2: `=B2&" "&COUNTIF($B$1:$B2,B2)`
(This basically creates an index that we can use for a VLookUp)

2) In Range F2 down, put in the dates of which measurements were taken

3) In G2 put in the following formula: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($F2&" "&G$1,$A:$D,3,0),"")`
(This is looking up the first time for the given date)

4) In H2 put in the following formula: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($F2&" "&H$1,$A:$D,4,0),"")`
(This is looking up the first reading for the given date)

5) Copy these formulas down for as many days as there are readings listed.

6) Copy columns G & H to the right for as many columns as you like, but iterating the titles by 1 each time.

Please see below for example:

```
Index       Date        Time        Reading     Date        1       1       2       2       3           3       4           4
42005 1     1/1/2015    1:18:20     13.4        1/1/2015    1:18:20 13.4    6:04:59 8.7     21:16:57    21.1        
42005 2     1/1/2015    6:04:59     8.7         1/2/2015    0:12:53 20.2    6:52:06 16.1    11:03:25    20.8    15:47:29    15.3
42005 3     1/1/2015    21:16:57    21.1        1/3/2015    0:06:23 13.4    6:31:24 19.3                
42006 1     1/2/2015    0:12:53     20.2                                        
42006 2     1/2/2015    6:52:06     16.1                                        
42006 3     1/2/2015    11:03:25    20.8                                        
42006 4     1/2/2015    15:47:29    15.3                                        
42006 5     1/2/2015    16:36:51    12                                      
42006 6     1/2/2015    20:11:22    9.1                                     
42007 1     1/3/2015    0:06:23     13.4                                        
42007 2     1/3/2015    6:31:24     19.3
```

Comment: I've tried your solution Demetri. Don't understand " In Range F2 down, put in the dates of which measurements were taken". I pasted in the dates from Column B. Otherwise entered all formulas as suggested. Got some repeated data from G2 - G10 and H2-H8.That's it.

Comment: I'm sorry, Patrice, that the solution did not work out for you.  I tried to provide an example of the output to show roughly how it was intended to work, and modified the solution slightly so that it would output a little cleaner.  I hope that helps, or perhaps that what @pnuts suggested will prove more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Date` is in A1, on a copy please insert a new ColumnA and in A2 copied down to suit:

```
 =B1=B2
```

In E2 and copied across to suit (ie until only blank cells in an *entire* column):

```
=IF(COLUMN()-3<2*COUNTIF($B:$B,$B2),OFFSET($C2,INT((COLUMN()-1)/2)-1,ISEVEN(COLUMN())),"")
```

Series fill C1:D1 across to suit.

Select and Copy entire sheet, Paste Special..., Values over the top. Filter on ColumnA to select `TRUE` and delete those rows. Format columns to suit.